# iOS universal links only opens app if "path" has a specific syntax with regards to linebreaks and spaces

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

im trying to set up universal links in a react-native project, thought this part shouldt have anything to do with react-native.

i have uploaded the file correctly at: example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

i created a simple html file to test the universal link:
[open](https://example.com/)

but im having a wierd problem where the syntax of the "path" section determines if the universal link works or not.

this does not work:

syntax 1:

```
"paths": [
   "*"
]
```

syntax 2:

```
"paths": ["*"]
```

however, this works:

syntax 3:

```
"paths": [ "*" ]
```

i prefer syntax 1, as i think its the most clean one. especially if i start adding more routes. i want this one to work, i dont want to use syntax 2 or 3.

i also checked some other websites like facebook and youtube, and they all have the syntax 1, with linebreaks for every path.

i cant imagine why linebreaks and spaces have any effect. what could possibly be an explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found the problem, its not spaces or linebreaks that determined if my deep links worked or not. i made a typo. i find it weird that the typo only broke the deep links in some circumstances and not others, but oh well.

i wrote the `applinks` property with camelcase, like so: `appLinks`. it should all be lowercase. `applinks` is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this process is very sensitive in my experience.  Line breaks and spaced DO matter.
Also make sure you're using the correct structure of the file, as there have been some changes and some guides are out of date and mix and matching the formats can get a little weird.

I normally use both of these validators to make sure the file is read properly:

1. [Branch.IO](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/)
2. [Apple](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool)

Comment: i have been unable to find any official documentation for this. do you know if any such documentation exists? i feel like this should be explicitly documented.
also, do you know why it works for websites like youtube? they seem to have a line break for every route in the path array.